# Android Opencv resize image

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have square area for detection and I replace square area with image but now I have a problem because the image is too large for the square area. So I'd like to resize the image in order to has the same size with the square area.
How I can resize the image? 
You can look at my GIF below this post

[image]

My Code:

```
Core.rectangle(rgbaInnerWindow, new Point(pt.x-radius,pt.y-radius), new Point(pt.x+radius,pt.y+radius), new Scalar(255));

Mat mask = new Mat(rgbaInnerWindow.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

Mat dst = new Mat();

Imgproc.resize(img1, dst, mask.size());     

dst.copyTo(rgbaInnerWindow);
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: @Miki oh I'm sorry I forgot the question. How I Can resize the image?

Comment: with `resize` :D Probably you have problem copying it in the correct location?

Comment: @Miki I don't know the correct location because the image is full screen, so I'd like to resize the image. Can you guide me to do something, please?

Comment: Your `dst` is already the resized image. I really don't understand what's missing here..

Comment: @Miki `rgbaInnerWindow.size()` is full screen size and I'd like to `Mat mask` = `rectangle` size. I don't know how to create `rectangle.size()` for  `Mat mask`

Comment: `Mat mask = new Mat(rectangle.height, rectangle.width, CvType.CV_8UC1)`

Comment: @Miki it doesn't work :( I will try another way. thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: That will create mask of the correct size. Of course your code will crash at `copyTo`. You should, however, take your time to post a **clear** question, and showing the errors you have

Comment: @Miki you can see GIF at my answer